# Suppose $\ker( \textsf{T}_{i+1} ) = \operatorname{im}( \textsf{T}_i )$. Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i \dim (\textsf{V}_i ) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $\textsf{T}_i :\textsf{V}_i \to \textsf{V}_{i+1}$ ($i=  0,\dots,n$) is a sequence of vector spaces such that 
$$\ker( \textsf{T}_{i+1} ) = \operatorname{im}( \textsf{T}_i )$$
with $\textsf{V}_0 = \textsf{V}_{n+1} = \{0\}$. Show that $$\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i \dim (\textsf{V}_i ) = 0$$

Comment: Any thoughts? $\ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The rank-nullity theorem tells you that for each $i$,
$$
\dim( V_i) = \dim \ker(T_i) + \dim \operatorname{im}(T_i)
$$
which by our condition means that
$$
\dim( V_i) = \dim \ker(T_i) + \ker(T_{i+1})
$$

---

It is notable that these maps form what's known as a [long exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Long_exact_sequence). A useful exercise to understand a bit of what's happening is as follows: describe the maps $T_0$ and $T_{n}$.  Show that the map $T_1$ is injective, and the map $T_{n-1}$ is surjective.